# Making a quiz in html/javascript alerts not working

Tags: javascript, html

Making a simple multiple choice, short answer and multiple response quiz on peanut butter and jelly :). What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the "submit" button it shows the number of correct or incorrect answers. Also, next to the question show if the choice they chose was correct or incorrect, for example on the multiple choice question, if they select the right answer(jelly) then it would say "correct!" next to that option. Right now when I click submit nothing is happening, not sure why, I thought it would pop up an alert with the amount correct but nothing happens. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple but for some reason it hasn't popped out for me so any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <title>
    How to make a proper Peanut Butter and Jelly
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src = "scripts/main.js"></script>


</head>  

<body>

    <header>

    </header>   
    <main>
    <form id = "quiz" name = "quiz">

    <p>what item do you use to spread peanut butter on the bread?</p>
    <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "question1">

    <p>what is one ingrediant of peanut butter and jelly sandwich?</p>
    <input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "cheese"> cheese <br>
    <input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "bacon"> bacon <br>
    <input type = "radio" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "jelly"> jelly <br>

    <p>which of the following are correct ingredients required to make a Peanut Butter and Jelly sandwich?</p>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "bread"> bread <br>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "cheese"> cheese <br>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "peanut butter"> peanut butter <br>   
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "jelly"> jelly <br>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "mc" name = "question2" value = "toothpaste"> toothpaste <br>
    <br>

    <input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Submit Quiz" onclick = "check():">
    <br>




    </form>





</main> 



    <footer>

    </footer> 
</body>
```

javascript code

```
    function src(){
var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;

if (question1 == "knife")
{
alert("correct!");
correct++;
}
else{
alert("incorrect");
incorrect++;
}

if(question2 == "jelly")
{
alert("correct!");
correct++;
}
else{
alert("incorrect");
incorrect++;
}
if(question3 == "bread"||"jelly"||"peanut butter"){
alert("correct!");
correct++
}
else{
alert("incorrect");
incorrect;
}

alert(correct);




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you seem like you are familiar with other programming languages. such as C# or java for example but you don't know the basics of DOM manipulation. So bear with me now till I explain it to you in brief details.

first of all, the DOM is the (Document Object Model) it is basically the image created using your mark up language (HTML). basically this is the things displayed on the browser and manipulated by javascript. like the buttons on this page or the text box I'm typing right now or the navigation bar above.

So, a quick recap the DOM is created using HTML and manipulated using javascript.

As the DOM is created by the html you won't be able to manipulate it until it till the html is loaded. you adding the script tag on the top of the html page means you run the manipulating things that are not there. So, you have to add the script tag at the end of the html page before the body closing tag.

```
   <script src = "scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now, when you want to manipulate an element you have to store it in a variable and the way to do this is by using a selector.

You have three options but just to save time I won't state the 3 I will state the best and most commonly used one. you can google the others but I don't think it is worth it though.

so if you know css you select a component wether by its name or id or class.
there is something in javascript called query selector and it is used like this.

```
var x = document.queryselector('css-selector');
```

Instead of the css-selector part you add a css selector.
for example if the element has a class of 'hero'. you will replace css-selector with .hero or if it has the id of 'hero' you will replace the css-selector with #id.

Then you should use the variable name to manipulate the element.

here are more useful links that you can check out.
[JavaScript](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQJDWD5lhO0&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVDrpgRUPpKGw6dit0kpE3J&index=8)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the colon : on the submit button onclick

```
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Submit Quiz" onclick = "check():">
```

Change this to

```
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Submit Quiz" onclick = "check()">
```

Comment: I tried that and still nothing happens when I click "submit quiz" :/ @raj crk

Comment: Try changing your code to `onclick= "src()"` @Progamminnoob

Comment: still no results, nothing happens :( @raj crk

Comment: your html code has function name as check `<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Submit Quiz" onclick = "check():">` but the javascript function name is `src()`@Progamminnoob

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your submit onclick handler is `check()`. But you have no function called `check()`. Did you mean to do

`onclick = "src()">`

instead?

Do note that you should put all of your Javascript in the Javascript - it's bad practice to put handlers in the HTML, it'll only make things harder for you in the long run. Strongly consider using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: I made the change "onclick = "src()"> but still the button isn't doing anything? @certainperformance

Comment: Your Javascript is invalid here: `else{ alert("incorrect"); incorrect; }` Always check the browser console for errors first.

Comment: opps, forgot to add the ++ to incorrect. that still doesn't cause my submit button to work though. @certainPerformance

Comment: Try attaching the function with Javascript (rather than HTML), and then check your browser console for errors.

Comment: thats what im confused on, not sure of the proper formatting to put that function into my javascript file @certainPerformance

Comment: See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167522/discussion-between-progamminnoob-and-certainperformance).